# can't add a new function to String class via prototype in as2

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, mtasc

following code;

```
String.prototype.myFunction = function() { trace("my function is called"); };
var myString:String = "myString";
myString.myFunction();
```

causes this error with mtasc compiler:

> type error String has no field myFunction

it must be possible to add new functions to a class via prototype.

is there any configuration i can do for mtasc to be able to compile this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was specifying type information at myString variable definition.

it is compilable and working in that case:

```
String.prototype.myFunction = function() { trace("my function is called"); };
var myString = "myString";
myString.myFunction();
```